# How can I control one variable in different counters

Tags: javascript, html, variables, counter

I designed a counter, each has 3 buttons (up, down and remove counter). And I can add counter. Each new counter works great, but other counters continue counting from new counter. I think i should create array of numers n, and for n(i) we should have count(i) ? If is it true then how i can do it?

How can I fix that?

```
    var up = document.getElementsByClassName("up");
    var n = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
        up[i].addEventListener("click", function (){
            var input = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("input");
                    n++;
                    input[0].innerHTML = parseInt( input[0].innerHTML ) + 1;
        });
    };


    <button class="up">up</button>
    <div class="input">0</div>
```

Comment: This reads as a "do my work for me" sort of request. Please ask a *specific* question for which part you're struggling with, and reduce the code you've posted to be a [mcve] (extra emphasis on *minimal*).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the event listeners to each 'up' and 'down' element every time you run `upDownCounter()`

So the first counters on the page get the click listener each time - if you add a `console.log()` inside your event listeners you see it run multiple times for the older counters.

```
up[i].addEventListener("click", function (){
    console.log('up click'
    ...
});
```

If you have 3 counters, then click 'up' on the first one will log "up click" 3 times, the second one will log it twice and the newest 1 once, as it will have only had the event listener added once.

Also, I think you var scoping is off, your `n` variable is common to all the counters, it needs to be declared inside the click handler.
You could use this instead:

```
input[0].innerHTML = parseInt( input[0].innerHTML ) + 1;
```

The code could do with some refactoring though, it repeats itself a lot and is a little hard to follow.